# Dynamic Import Resolution: Identifying Imported Classes (fromList)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to find a solution to the Circular Import problem by rewriting the import statement to make it dynamic. During testing, something came up that I couldn't find information about.

Assuming I only have a folder named "test/" containing "**__init__.py**" and "**load.py**". In the **load.py** file, I have:

`from test import ClassA, ClassB`

What I would like to know is if it's possible to identify in **__init__.py** that I'm trying to import ClassA and ClassB, something like this in **__init__.py**:

`print(imported_classes) # Result: ['ClassA', 'ClassB']`

File Structure

```
test/
test/__init__.py
test/load.py

# another option
anywhere/load.py
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are ClassA and ClassB modules?

Comment: @spenpal Class, not module

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your file directory structure? I am a little confused about where ClassA and ClassB are coming from.

Comment: This is not the way to resolve circular import issues.

Comment: @spenapl Done. In the case of load.py, it can be located anywhere. The main idea is that in the import statement of the test module, I can dynamically obtain the fromlist of the import.

Comment: @wim Certainly, I am aware of that. It is just the tip of the iceberg. I have already resolved the circular part; I just want to make it dynamic.

Comment: If you want print statements to activate whenever a module requests objects from another module, the activation needs to be done from the perspective of the requesting module (e.g. `load.py`), not the object source module (`test/__init__.py`). This is because under the standard Python import mechanism, modules are only executed once, on the first import request; subsequent imports request the module from the cache `sys.modules`.

Comment: @dROOOze I had hoped that it would be possible to use inspect to obtain "who called me" or "the line that executed me" to retrieve the information without much processing cost.